# Select rows that if I sum their value = 0 from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
ID.          Location.      Value.          
1.            AGF.           10.00
2.            VHJ.           -20.00
3.            AGF.           -20.00
4.            AGF.           5.00
5.            KLZ.           50.00
6.            AGF.           10.00
```

I want to select the rows that have same **Location** AND whose **Value**s sum to zero.

In this case the result should be:

```
1
3
6
```

because those rows are all in Location **AGF** and they sum to 0 (10 + -20 + 10).

Comment: `The results am expecting should be 1 3 6` . Can you explain how the sum is 0 for these records?

Comment: the description of the question does not match exactly with the result you expected because the sum of AGF. is 5, not 0... so im not sure how to ommit the row 4....

Comment: I guess OP wants to show only those records for a `Location` where the `SUM` of those locations equals 0. Hence Row 4 is excluded for Location `AGF` because then the SUM becomes 5

Comment: Are you saying that you want to find any combination of the rows for certain location that would have a total of 0 when calculated together regardless of the other rows for that location? That's really not something you would want to do in SQL.

Comment: Yes Mr JamesZ exactly what I mean

Comment: What if more than one combination of rows will total to 0? I.e., if there were rows: `7. AGF 10.00`, `8. AGF -10.00` ?  Would you get 1,3,6, then 7, 8, and 1,8, and 6,8, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Select ID from YourTable where Location IN(
    Select location from YouTable 
    Group By Location 
    Having sum(Value) = 0
)
```

Comment: according to the question, with sum of AGF. its 5, not 0... so the result is not the expected.

Comment: If you have:  `7.            AGF.                10.00` then what it should be?

Comment: Its like grouping the rows by the sum value = 0 and leave the other rows that don't with the condition that I stated

Comment: yes tirma he is right  that select it is not working in this case because there is some rows that if you add them they will equal 0 then skip the rest that if you add them also don't equale 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all locations with zero sum using grouping and group filters (`group by` and `having` clauses respectively). This can be done in a subquery. Then select all IDs with the just selected locations.

```
select ID
  from YOUR_TABLE
  where Location in (
    select Location
      from YOUR_TABLE
      group by Location
      having sum(Value) = 0
  )
```

Comment: according to the question, with sum of AGF. its 5, not 0... so the result is not the expected.

Comment: Iwant yo eliminate that row and only keep those that sum =0 and so on

Comment: lets do it this way select only the rows that if you sum there Value will = 0 for example   select * from mytable where sum(Value) = 0 how i can do this

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, like this:

```
Select ID from tablelocation where Location IN(
    Select location from tablelocation 
    Group By Location 
    Having sum(Value) = 0
)
```

Comment: see here the sum is 5 when location is AGF. because there are ID 4 is also AGF and it's value is 5 so,,,,this is not possible

Comment: Yes I want the select to eliminate that row as Mr JamesZ say above I want only the rows that sum =0 and eliminate others and so on